# How to require an attribute to be null if another attribute is not, and require one to be not null if another is not null?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, boot

Simply, in one of my entities I want to require an attribute to be null if another attribute is null and reverse.

Specifically, I want a timeslot to require an employee if the activity is not null. And reverse, if there's no activity, employee should be null.

After I saw that you can require uniqueness based on two attributes instead of one with:

`@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"customer", "timeslot"})})`

I thought it must be possible to do what I want to do as well.

I just don't know how I specify it in JPA.

Comment: What you describe sounds like business logic, not database constraint. It belongs to the service layer, not the database.